# Failed conversion of string to smalldatetime but only on 1 out of 4 accounts

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

A small application to manage our stock in which there is an option to edit how much got taken out and to what department it went. To get the correct value a SELECT is used containing the date on which it got taken out:

```
CAST(date AS smalldatetime) = '" + Convert.ToDateTime(date_value).ToString("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss") + "'
```

The application is run on 4 pc's with different users. 3 of them are working perfectly fine but the 4th throws the error below. What could reason of such an error seeing it only effect's 25% of the users.

(all were tested with the same records)

[image: The Error]

Comment: Windows culture/language settings.

Comment: Stop passing the data to SQL Server as *strings*. It's a really bad habit. Pass it *as* a DateTime (via parameters) and you avoid constantly converting between datatypes.

Comment: @UweKeim you were right. for some reason this PC was the only one in the department with local settings instead of US

Comment: @A.bakker that's why you *shouldn't* use string concatenation to pass values. Use parameterized queries. You won't have to do parse/format anything either

Answer (score 1):

The `MMM` part in the `dd-MMM-yy` format is language especific. You can find `JAN` in english or `ENE` in spanish (Enero), and this is configured at the OS level. Also, some regions' format interchange the day with the month, so you can't possibly know without doubts if `01-03-1900` is the first of March or the third of January.

You shouldn't work with strings if you need to handle dates, you should use the proper date format as a parameter, as Damien suggested. So remove the `ToString()` method and use the `DateTime` class directly.

If somehow you need to parse a string that's a date, try to generate it on the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format, which is `yyyy-mm-dd` for dates or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` for datetimes (note the Z for UTC).

Comment: . . Although I prefer YYYY-MM-DD for date formats, I prefer that for human-generated input.  If the code is being generated for SQL Server, the constant should drop the hyphens (YYYYMMDD) because that is unambiguous regardless of internationalization settings.